# The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SiparisMaster?'

Tags: flutter, dart

The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SiparisMaster?'.

How can I convert an object of type to a class I want?

[image]

```html
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'siparis_master.freezed.dart';
part 'siparis_master.g.dart';

@freezed
class SiparisMaster with _$SiparisMaster {
  const SiparisMaster._();

  factory SiparisMaster({
    int? field1,
    DateTime? field2,
    int? field3
    String? field4,
  }) = _SiparisMaster;

  factory SiparisMaster.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) =>
      _$SiparisMasterFromJson(map);
}
```

Comment: Please share `SiparisMaster` class code so as your `masterObj` `Map`.

Comment: Seems like there is a `fromJson` method, try using it this way : `master : SiparisMaster.fromJson(masterObj)`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method, or better, a constructor for your class, which accept a Map as argument

```dart
class SiparisMaster {
   SiparisMaster.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map){
      attribute1 = map['attribute1'];
      attribute2 = map['attribute2'];
   }
}
```

and then you call it in the function `copyWith`

```dart
teslimat.masterDetayTemp = teslimat.masterDetayTemp?.copyWith(
   master: SiparisMaster.fromMap(masterObj)
)
```